# SQL Server 2012 Express - Logs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

Newbie question.

I have a SQL Server 2012 Express. Each day we do a full backup and get it FTP'd off site using a 3rd party tool. We don't need incremental backups or other things. If there is a problem, then entire database would get restored, which is fine.

To keep the size of the database small, how do I clean out the logs that I don't need. I noticed they are getting big.

Comment: Maybe you are in full recovery mode.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space